# Can't detect home parition during installation or in GParted

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, gparted, home-directory, disk

I have two partitions on my SSD disk, one for root mounted at /, and one for home folder mounted at /home.

The problem is that GParted doesn't detect the home partition, it thinks that it doesn't exist and count it along with other free space:

[image: GParted Image]

It's worth to mention that I get this message when I open GParted:

```
Partition(s) 1 on /dev/sda have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before making further changes.
```

But GNOME Disks does detect it:

[image: GNOME Disks]

And also while I was trying to install Mint 19, the same thing happened; It didn't detect the home partition and showed just the root partition.

But the home partition exists and it's working, I can browse its files and I am using it as for my home folder. Why isn't showing up? I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It is mounted. in df -hl I can see it has a separate partition for /home at /dev/sda1, and / is at /dev/sda2

Comment: Did you try rebooting as was suggested by the warning message?

Comment: Of course I did.

Comment: You might try to troubleshoot the issue by using other partition tools to view the partition layout.  For example:  `sudo fdisk -l -u /dev/sda`